# Missing auto-generated methods using ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am trying to learn Entity Framework. In the book that I am using, it guides me to creating a C# class library to house the entity framework model. Inside of this class library, I am instructed to add a new item and generate an ADO.NET Entity Data Model from an existing database (.NET 4).

After generating the classes, what I noticed is that the EntityObject classes were missing methods (like OnCustomerIDChanged, OnDueDateChanged, etc.). The classes only had property accessors and navigation properties. I did notice some files with .tt extensions.  It looks like there is a new way of dealing with objects in Entity Framework but as I am still learning EF, I'm wondering if there is a way to bring it back to generating the missing methods?  Thanks in advance for your help.

BTW, I tried using Visual Studio 2010 and it did create the methods I mentioned above. However, I'm wondering if it's possible make Visual Studio 2012 do the same since I've grown to like VS 2012.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to follow the book you should use VS 2010. EF has evolved and `EntityObject` based entities are considered obsolete.

Anyway if you want to force VS 2012 to behave in the same way as VS 2010 open your EDMX and in *Properties Window* change *Code generation strategy* to *Default* and save your EDMX file. After that you can delete all .tt files. All your entities will be generated in single .Designer.cs file.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ladislav. That solved my problem. As a side question and to guide my studies, what technique or technology replaced EntityObjects or how the code is generated?

Comment: POCO classes are used instead of `EntityObject` based entities and the code is generated through T4 templates (.tt files).